# Как добавить span к ссылкам во вложенном меню?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Начинаю постигать азы натяжки вёрстки на WordPress и не могу понять, как добавить внутрь ссылок span со своим классом что бы был именно во вложенных списках?

```
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 2</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu-1">
      <li><a href="#">Ссылка в подменю 1</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu-2">
          <li><a href="#">Ссылка в подменю 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Пробовал через вот такую функцию но добавляет всем ссылкам, а нужно именно вложенным...

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_item_args', 'change_menu_item_args', 10, 3 );

function change_menu_item_args( $args, $item, $depth ) {
    if ( $args->theme_location = 'main' && $depth === 0 ) {
        $args->link_after = '<span class="my-class-link"></span>';
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решилось при помощи обычной функции...